# How to install silently on a remote computer?

Tags: c#, .net, installation

I want to install an application on a remote computer. I run the setup.exe file by Win32_Process but, it does not work. the outparameter of Win32_Process returns Zero (based on MSDN-WMI, it means the process runs completely) and i can see my setup.exe process line on the process list of the remote computer but in reality it did not run. No installation happen.

I can not work with setup.msi, because it does not install .net framework that i set as prerequisites.

How can i run a setup.exe silently on a remote computer?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried Advanced Installer. I is quite simply and would probably handle your silent install thing.
Here is the link
http://www.advancedinstaller.com/download.html

Read more no the silent install here
http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-silent-install.html

I have used it and it has a prerequisite option where you can add the .net 4.0 or any other version as a prerequisite to your EXE. You can specify the link for the download also. I suppose you can also make it work in the background

Comment: tnx for your answer but the remote computer is not allow to download, so the prerequisites should be installed from the folder beside the setup application. MSI application did not handle it.

Comment: Advanced Installer supports including the prerequisite and the MSI into a single EXE setup file. If this is not what you need. Can you please give us more details?

Comment: i need to install the prerequisite from specific folder beside the installation path, i don't know if advanced installer support it or not but i will check Advanced Installer. tnx.

Answer (score 1):

Normally a package is delivered silently through a distribution system such as SCCM or similar that operates at an Active Directory level.

However, you should be able to install remotely using the **setup.exe command line parameters for an Installshield setup** if the setup in question has been created using Installshield.

The overall idiea is that you pass command line to the msi inside the setup by the /v parameter followed by a valid msiexec command line. The /s is used to run silent. I don't have a setup.exe to try right now, but this should work:

```
setup.exe /s /v"/L*v c:\log.log /qn"
```

Here are some good links:

- [Running Setup from the Command Line](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259299%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)
- [Setup.exe and Update.exe Command-Line Parameters](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield20helplib/Content/helplibrary/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm)
- [Appendix B. InstallShield Command-Line Parameters](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/pcomhelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.pcomm.doc/books/html/install_guide12.htm)